# launching Here maps navigation via intent

Tags: android, here-api

I'd like to launch the navigation (by car) from my current position to the one saved as 'home' with a single action.
It seems it can be done using intent, but the one I've tried (Data:google.navigation:q="my address") open the app with destination = my address, but I have to click on "DIRECTIONS" for seeing the routes.
Is there a way for the intent to avoid that manual step?
Thanks.
Luigi.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working using the following:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("here.directions://v1.0/mylocation/37.870090,-122.268150?m=w")
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
intent.setPackage("com.here.app.maps")
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Here maps:

> Construct an Intent with the following properties:
>
> action: com.here.maps.DIRECTIONS
>
> category: CATEGORY_DEFAULT
>
> data URI:
>
> here.directions://v1.0/mylocation/37.870090,-122.268150,Downtown%20Berkeley?ref=&m=w

https://developer.here.com/documentation/mobility-on-demand-toolkit/topics/navigation.html

---

If you want to use Google maps:

Action: `android.intent.action.VIEW`

DataUri: `google.navigation:q=[address to search]&mode=[walking / transit]`

> Query
>
> q: Sets the end point for navigation searches. This can be a
> latitude,longitude or a query formatted address. If it is a query
> string that returns more than one result, the first result will be
> selected.
>
> Mode: mode sets the method of transportation. Mode is optional,
> defaults to driving, and can be set to one of:
>
> d: for driving w for walking b for bicycling
>
> Avoid: avoid sets features the route should try to avoid. Avoid is
> optional and can be set to one or more of:
>
> t: for tolls h for highways f for ferries

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: Thanks. I had seen also that, but it seems it works worse than the one I tried:
- how do I set 'current position' instead of 37.870090,-122.268150?
- if I set an italian address (via Roma 14 Milano) instead of Downtown%20Berkeley in Here maps I have destination = via Roma 14 Milano Bekerly CA 94704 USA

Thanks.