# How to open link the apps to open the here maps directly?

Tags: android, here-maps-rest

Following is the way open the google maps directly:

Action:
android.intent.action.VIEW

Activity class:
com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity

Activity package
com.google.android.apps.maps

How about for here maps?

Comment: Please see my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994098/5498630) with a working example

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

Construct an Intent with the following properties:

Action `com.here.maps.DIRECTIONS`

Category `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`

Data URI 
`here.directions://v1.0/mylocation/SRC_LAT,SRC_LNG,DST_LAT,DST_LNG?ref=<Referrer>&m=w`

for more info see [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/mobility-on-demand-toolkit/topics/navigation.html)

Comment: before apply this, we need download the here wego apps first right? Do u have extra information about the activity class, and activity package?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but I wrote a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@michaelganchas4/android-tutorial-open-navigation-for-google-maps-waze-and-here-wego-e40bf0cc4bfe) on how to open Waze, Google Maps, and HERE WeGo navigation through intents.